# recv function on the server side, gives me -1 and not 0 if the connection was lost

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm trying to find out when the server loses connection to the client.
on the server side I have the following code:

```
send(m_connectedSocket, Com, (unsigned)strlen(Com), 0);

char* buf = new char[*size];
int timeout = 1000; 

int err = setsockopt(m_connectedSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)& timeout, sizeof(int));
*size = recv(m_connectedSocket, buf, *size, 0);

 cout << *size << " " << m_connectedSocket << endl;
```

console: (3 rows conected to client, then lost)

```
123 200
123 200
123 200
-1 200
-1 200
-1 200
```

in every description it is stated that if the connection is lost, the return value of recv = 0. this also works wonderfully on the client side. but on the server side, I always get -1 one back when the client is switched off?
I guess it's the timeout?

EDIT: In this case the client is kill and not correct shutdown

I have to find out somehow whether the server has lost the connection so that the client can reconnect. if I would trigger on -1, there is no guarantee that the connection was lost ...

Comment: How is the connection lost? 0 is if the client properly ends the connection and says "I'm done now, bye!" "Bye!". Any other kind of connection loss is an error.

Comment: `errno` will say what is happening exactly, e.g. use `strerror(errno)` for printing.

Comment: ah ok thx, then i have to find out if the connection is unexpectedly lost.
At the moment I close the program without closing the connection properly and I have to detect this case.
is there a trick?
Strangely, it works on the client side (recv = 0) if I simply turn off the server without terminating the connection

Answer (score 1):

> in every description it is stated that if the connection is lost, the return value of recv = 0.

Those descriptions are wrong. The recv = 0 value indicates that the connection was **gracefuly closed** by the peer. However, the connection can be abnormally lost instead, in which case you will receive -1, and then you should inspect `errno` for more info.

Comment: Errnor call then "No Error"